Turbo-Stream broadcast and Sidekiq job - Job runs, but page does not update
Trying to run a sidekiq job then broadcast the updated attributes to the page assuming the user is sitting there watching it.
I'll try and list all relevant code:
cable.yml
development:
  adapter: redis
  url: redis://localhost:6379/1

test:
  adapter: test

production:
  adapter: redis
  url: <%= ENV.fetch("REDIS_URL") { "redis://localhost:6379/1" } %>
  channel_prefix: archmage_production

app/jobs/hourly_user_update_job.rb
class HourlyUserUpdateJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform
    User.find_each do |user|
      user.increment!(:gold, 100)
      broadcast_gold_update(user)
    end
  end

  private

  def broadcast_gold_update(user)
    Turbo::StreamsChannel.broadcast_replace_to(
      "user-info", # Name of the Turbo stream
      target: "user-info-gold",
      html: user.gold.to_s
    )
  end
end

_user_info.html.haml
<turbo-frame id="user-info">
  <div class="user-info-panel">
    <h3>User Information</h3>
    <p><strong>Username:</strong> <%= user.username %></p>
    <p><strong>Email:</strong> <%= user.email %></p>
    <p><strong>Total Gold:</strong><span id="user-info-gold"> <%= user.gold %></span></p>
    <p><strong>Total Mana:</strong> <%= user.mana %></p>
    <p><strong>Land:</strong> <span id="user-info-land"><%= user.land %></span></p>
    <%= render 'shared/active_spells', user: user %>
  </div>
</turbo-frame>

The job:
3.1.2 :002 > HourlyUserUpdateJob.perform_now
Performing HourlyUserUpdateJob (Job ID: f5b52007-e50b-4a5e-b767-6dbb14ba2271) from Async(default) enqueued at
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1000]]
  User Update All (1.0ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "gold" = COALESCE("gold", 0) + $1 WHERE "users"."id" = $2  [["gold", 100], ["id", 1]]
[ActionCable] Broadcasting to user-info: "<turbo-stream action=\"replace\" target=\"user-info-gold\"><template>100900</template></turbo-stream>"
Performed HourlyUserUpdateJob (Job ID: f5b52007-e50b-4a5e-b767-6dbb14ba2271) from Async(default) in 24.5ms
 => nil


how did you implement your html page ?

Added the html.haml (user-info)

you need to add turbo_stream_from on your page to create a subscription to listen stream data 'user-info'.

OMG thank you! that did it.
